# Сравнительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

Мучилась долго, но у меня с приведением частного к общему некоторые проблемы, поэтому прошу помощи.

Он чувствовал себя как человек, который начал учить древние иероглифы.
и:
 Он не выглядел, как человек, у которого всё хорошо — несмотря на уютный дом и милый район вокруг.

В обоих случаях это - сравнительные обороты? Со значением приравнивания? Почему тогда в одном случае есть запятая, а во втором - нет? Нужна ли запятая во втором случае?
Спасибо.

Comment: _Sionnah: Нужна ли запятая во втором случае?_ === Перед "как человек" — не нужна. А вот после "всё хорошо"... А где Вы нашли эти предложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая перед союзом КАК **не ставится в обоих случаях**, что соответствует правилу Розенталя:

*Он **чувствовал себя как человек**, который начал учить древние иероглифы.

Он **не выглядел как человек,** у которого всё хорошо, — несмотря на уютный дом и милый район вокру*г.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

**1) Правило Розенталя**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми:

   ...если сравнительный оборот входит в сказуемое (образует именную часть составного сказуемого) или **по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота)**: *Он выглядел как человек больной;*

**2) Примечание**

*Он не выглядел как человек, **у которого всё хорошо**, — несмотря на уютный дом и милый район вокруг.*

**Придаточное предложение нужно закрыть запятой.** Присоединительный оборот, обособленный тире, относится ко всему предложению. При отсутствии запятой он будет относиться только к придаточному предложению